# How do I alert the variable using url segment with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I am using HVC codeigniter.
I wanted to alert the value of variable.

Here's the code on my view.

```
$("#user_table tr").click(function(){    
$userid = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
$.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "manageUser_controller/log_history/$userid",
         success: function(data){
            alert(data);
          }
      });

    });
```

Here's the code on my controller.

```
function log_history($userid) {
    echo $userid;
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your code as follows

```
var userid = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();

url: "manageUser_controller/log_history/'+userid,
```

Answer (score 0):

try to send as data  like this

```
    $("#user_table tr").click(function(){    
      var userid = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
       $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "manageUser_controller/log_history",
                data:{userid : userid},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                 }
              });

      });
```

and get it on controller using input post like this

```
function log_history() 
{
    $user_id = $this->input->post('userid',true);
    echo $userid;
}
```

it's also be filter by true.